# Where does the clothing for the crew of the International Space Station come from?

Tags: iss, astronaut-lifestyle, psychology

This [post](https://www.quora.com/What-clothes-do-Astronauts-pack-for-space-missions-and-how-many) talked about the standardized clothing list each astronaut or cosmonaut has when on the ISS. It is specified carefully in consideration of the fact clothing can't be washed, so it is used and then discarded. This is the list:

> - 1 pair of shoes for the treadmill
> - 1 pair of shoes for the bike
> - 1 pair of exercise shorts for every 3 days of exercise
> - 1 T-shirt for every 3 days of exercise
> - 1 work shirt for every 10 days
> - 1 T-shirt for under the workshirt for every 10 days
> - 1 pair work pants/shorts for every 10 days
> - 1 pair underwear for every 2 days
> - 1 pair socks for every 2 days
> - 2 sweaters
> - 2 pairs Russian overalls (optional)

Does the space agency of the crew member issue this clothing? Do they get to pick anything themselves for that wardrobe from their personal stuff?

Is there anything special about the clothing? Because in videos of the ISS, you see how much storage is used for clothing, both new and discarded.

Clothing stored in the docking tube joining the Russian and American sections of the ISS (video [here](https://youtu.be/afBm0Dpfj_k?t=24m24s)):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how, but [Sam Christoferreti somehow got a Star Trek uniform on the station](https://twitter.com/AstroSamantha/status/589035429879513088) for a tribute to _["There's coffee in that nebula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtmF8RRxBXg)"_, by Kathryn Janeway (Kate Mulgrew) in Star Trek Voyager (SpaceX CRS-6 [delivered an espresso machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_CRS-6#Secondary_payload) to the station). Unless ESA secretly joined the United Federation of Planets, that uniform couldn't have been officially issued. :)

Comment: There's a variety of musical instruments on the ISS, and crew can bring some amount of personal items with them. Given all that, I suppose should come as no surprise that at least one ISS crewmember would be a Trek fan and bring some such artifact with them. Surely not the only example of such.

Answer (score 3):

Two producers I am aware of:

1. [NPP Zvezda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPP_Zvezda)  produces [ПК-14](http://www.zvezda-npp.ru/ru/node/115).
2. [Kentavr-Nauka](http://www.federalspace.ru/20320/) produces [some other things](http://english.pravda.ru/news/science/04-11-2003/53604-0/).

Be prepared to use google translate.